# Map each row into a list and collect all

Tags: python, python-polars

I have a dataframe:

```
df = pl.DataFrame(
    {
        "t_left": [0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0],
        "t_right": [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0],
        "counts": [1, 2, 3, 4],
    }
)
```

And I want to map each row into a list, and then collect all values (to be passed into e.g. `matplotlib.hist`)

I can do it by hand like:

```
times = []
for t_left, t_right, counts in df.rows():
    times.extend(np.linspace(t_left, t_right, counts + 1)[1:])
```

but this is painfully slow for my data set.

I am completely new to both python and polars, so I was wondering if there is a better way to achieve this.

**EDIT**

Complete copy-paste example to reproduce.

```
import polars as pl
import numpy as np

size = 1000000
df = pl.DataFrame(
    {
        "t_left": np.random.rand(size),
        "t_right": np.random.rand(size) + 1,
        "counts": [1] * size,
    }
)

times = []
for t_left, t_right, counts in df.rows():
    times.extend(np.linspace(t_left, t_right, counts + 1)[1:])
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you need the final result as one big list, you don't really need to work with lists, you can just [`explode()`](https://docs.pola.rs/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.Expr.explode.html) your dataframe into multiple rows so then you can run vectorized operations on it:

so, taking your example data:

```py
df = pl.DataFrame(
    {
        "t_left": [0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0],
        "t_right": [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0],
        "counts": [1, 2, 3, 4],
    }
)
┌────────┬─────────┬────────┐
│ t_left ┆ t_right ┆ counts │
│ ---    ┆ ---     ┆ ---    │
│ f64    ┆ f64     ┆ i64    │
╞════════╪═════════╪════════╡
│ 0.0    ┆ 1.0     ┆ 1      │
│ 1.0    ┆ 2.0     ┆ 2      │
│ 2.0    ┆ 3.0     ┆ 3      │
│ 3.0    ┆ 4.0     ┆ 4      │
└────────┴─────────┴────────┘
```

Now, let's create some columns we can use for our calculation. To calculate evenly distributed numbers you need a starting point - `t_left`, step - `(t_right - t_left) / counts` and then you need to repeat it `counts` times.

```py
# Thanks @Hericks for pointing out that code could be simplified even more
times = df.select(
    start = pl.col('t_left'),
    step = ((pl.col("t_right") - pl.col("t_left")) / pl.col("counts")),
    i = pl.int_ranges(1, pl.col('counts') + 1)
).explode('i')

# my old code
# times = df.select(
#    start = pl.col('t_left').repeat_by('counts').explode(),
#    step = ((pl.col("t_right") - pl.col("t_left")) / pl.col("counts")).repeat_by('counts').explode(),
#    i = pl.int_ranges(1, pl.col('counts') + 1).explode()
#)

┌───────┬──────────┬─────┐
│ start ┆ step     ┆ i   │
│ ---   ┆ ---      ┆ --- │
│ f64   ┆ f64      ┆ i64 │
╞═══════╪══════════╪═════╡
│ 0.0   ┆ 1.0      ┆ 1   │
│ 1.0   ┆ 0.5      ┆ 1   │
│ 1.0   ┆ 0.5      ┆ 2   │
│ 2.0   ┆ 0.333333 ┆ 1   │
│ …     ┆ …        ┆ …   │
│ 3.0   ┆ 0.25     ┆ 1   │
│ 3.0   ┆ 0.25     ┆ 2   │
│ 3.0   ┆ 0.25     ┆ 3   │
│ 3.0   ┆ 0.25     ┆ 4   │
└───────┴──────────┴─────┘
```

now, it's just a matter of applying the formula and converting result [`to_list()`](https://docs.pola.rs/py-polars/html/reference/series/api/polars.Series.to_list.html):

```py
times.select(
    res = pl.col('start') + pl.col('step') * pl.col('i')
)['res'].to_list()

[1.0, 1.5, 2.0, 2.3333333333333335, 2.6666666666666665, 3.0, 3.25, 3.5, 3.75, 4.0]
```

Comment: This is definitely the preferred solution as it fully relies on polars' native API. It could be further simplified by removing the `repeat_by([...]).explode()` expressions. Polars will take care of repeating the values based on the explosion of the column `i`.

Comment: @Hericks thanks. I've expected polars to take care of the explosion but it didn't really work for me - I got `Series length 4 doesn't match the DataFrame height of 10` exception

Comment: What version are you on? It works for me on version `0.20.5`.

Comment: @Hericks I think I was just doing it wrong, I just had to move `explode` outside of `select`. I'll add a note to the answer

Comment: Thanks, this gives a 100x improvement over my original code. I just have a question about the `explode` method.  Even though I understand what is happening, the link to the docs says that the method doesn't take any arguments. Am I missing something in the docs that points towards this behavior?

Comment: Good question, i need to change  the link to https://docs.pola.rs/py-polars/html/reference/dataframe/api/polars.DataFrame.explode.html#polars.DataFrame.explode - this one does accept arguments. I changed the code but forgot to change the link.

Answer (score 2):

**Update:**

This involves expanding the DataFrame by repeating each row according to its `counts` value. Then, for each of these expanded rows, it calculates a point in the linear space between `t_left` and `t_right`. This is done in a vectorized manner, which is significantly faster for large datasets like yours. The final output is a flattened array of these calculated values(suitable for plotting a histogram).

```
import polars as pl
import numpy as np

size = 1000000
df = pl.DataFrame(
    {
        "t_left": np.random.rand(size),
        "t_right": np.random.rand(size) + 1,
        "counts": np.random.randint(1, 10, size),  # Example counts
    }
)

# Create an expanded DataFrame by repeating rows based on 'counts'
max_count = df["counts"].max()
indices = pl.DataFrame({"idx": np.arange(max_count)})
expanded_df = df.join(indices, how="cross").filter(pl.col("idx") < pl.col("counts"))

# Calculate linearly spaced values across entire columns
times = expanded_df.with_columns(
    [
        ((pl.col("t_left") + 
          (pl.col("t_right") - pl.col("t_left")) / pl.col("counts") * pl.col("idx")).alias("time"))
    ]
).select("time").to_series().to_numpy().flatten()

print(times)
```

**Output:**

```
[0.61330023 0.84932839 1.08535655 ... 0.92804868 1.17410273 1.42015677]
```

Comment: I am trying this in a smaller data set (around 1M rows), and you version is ~2 times slower than my original version. The `polars` documentation explicitly mentions that `map_rows` is very slow; maybe that is the reason?

Comment: In that case you are correct. I updated my answer to include another approach; I attempted to use Polars' vectorized operations more extensively. So instead of applying a function to each row, i created a separate DataFrame of indices, then expanded the original DataFrame to match these indices. After that linearly spaced values are computed across the expanded DataFrame in a batch process.

Comment: I updated the question to generate a minimal fake data set. To me, the second approach is even slower than the first one. Do you see the same?

Comment: Does the 'counts' column in your DataFrame always contain the value 1, or does it vary? If it varies, do you need a list of linearly spaced values for each row based on 't_left', 't_right', and 'counts'?

Comment: `counts` is not fixed to 1 in my real data. Yes, I need `count` linearly spaced values between `t_left` (open) and `t_right` (closed).

Comment: I updated my answer(Check the updated code). It should be much quicker now

Comment: Thanks, this has equal performance as the other answer on a dataset like the one I gave in the question (~100x faster than my original code). But on a real data set it is about 2 times slower than the other proposed solution by @Roman Pekar. I think the reason is because in my data all `counts` are not a fixed number, so this cartesian product just generates a lot of unnecessary rows while the other method just expands exactly the rows it needs.